# Find max value in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following task :

An application that stores files, enables a user to add and delete files. When such an event occurs I append to a file in hdfs, the following record when there was a file added :

userid image-uuid size_in_bytes

and the following when a file was removed

-userid image-uuid size_in_bytes

When calculating the average in the reducer, I will have to subtract the size of the removed file and decrease the total to find the average without that file.

Deletions are infrequent events.

How could I calculate the average and max sizes of the whole dataset ?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that I also have a hadoop job that finds the max value per userID. So I will follow a divide and conquer approach. First find the max for each user, and then run a smaller job on the output to find the overall maximum.